# SQL - calculation made on values found in same table

Tags: sql

Assume that I have this table:

```
Name,date,value
Mr.X,2018-03-20,1
Mr.A,2018-03-20,10
Mr.B,2018-03-20,11
Mr.C,2018-03-20,12
Mr.A,2018-03-22,20
Mr.B,2018-03-22,22
Mr.C,2018-03-22,25
Mr.D,2018-03-22,42
```

How can I then generate this result:

```
Mr.A,10
Mr.B,11
Mr.C,13
```

I thus want to show all the names who appear on both dates and then show the difference in the value for the two days next to each person..

Comment: With a self-join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` the table to itself, matching the same person on different days:

```
select  d1.name
,       d2.value - d1.value
from    YourTable d1
join    YourTable d2
on      d1.date = '2018-03-20'
        and d2.date = 2018-03-22'
        and d1.name = d2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also be more dynamic with how to order your dates by using a row number to sequence the dates:

```
select 
  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name order by [Date]) [seq],
  Name,
  [Date] [Date1],
  [Value] [Value1],
  table2.[Date] [Date2],
  table2.[value] [Value2]
from table1
  join (select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name order by [Date]) [seq],
        Name,
        [Date],
        [Value]
    from table1)table2
on table1.Name = table2.Name
and table1.seq = table2.seq-1
```